# Extracting a substring from curl output through a regex

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying a come with a shell script where I need to grab zip files which are in a particular format, like `"${file_name}-12345.zip"` or `"${file_name}.zip"`.

Input to this shell script will be the output of `curl` command as shown below and the substring which is the `"${file_name}"`. In this case `file_name=foo_bar`.

```
<img src="/icons/compressed.gif" alt="[   ]"> 
<a href="foo_bar.zip">foo_bar.zip</a>
<img src="/icons/compressed.gif" alt="[   ]"> 
<a href="foo_bar-12345.zip">foo_bar-12345.zip</a>
<img src="/icons/compressed.gif" alt="[   ]"> 
<a href="foo_bar-12345_dup.zip">foo_bar-12345_dup.zip</a>
```

I need to grab only `foo_bar.zip` and `foo_bar-12345.zip` but not `foo_bar-12345_dup.zip`.

I need some direction in achieving this.

Comment: does `curl` return a valid html structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a regex like `(foo_bar\.zip)|(foo_bar-\d+\.zip)`. It means that you accept strings that are "foo_bar.zip" or strings such that "foo_bar" is followed by a dash and at least one digit (and a final ".zip"). Of course, you should replace "foo_bar" by the value of `${file_name}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the file name portion with `grep` and a regex and pipe it to `awk` to get the file name portion (assuming your files have .zip extension):

```
curl ... | grep -oE '>[[:alpha:]_]+\.zip<|>[[:alpha:]_]+-[[:digit:]]+\.zip<' | awk -F '[<>]' '{print $2}'
```

For your sample, you get:

```
foo_bar.zip
foo_bar-12345.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

```
curl command | grep -oP ">\K\w+-?\d*.zip"
```

`>\K` : positive lookbehind : To match the string ahead `>` but ignoring `>` as part of match;
`\w+-?\d*.zip` : your required regex;

Output:

```
foo_bar.zip
foo_bar-12345.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

curl something| awk -F'[">]' '!/_dup/&&/_bar/{print $2}'

```
foo_bar.zip
foo_bar-12345.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'sub(/.[^>]*/,"") && gsub(/>|<.*/,"") && (($0 ~ /foo_bar.zip/) || ($0 ~ /foo_bar-[0-9]+.zip/))'  Input_file
```

Non-one liner form of solution too as follows.

```
awk '
sub(/.[^>]*/,"") && \
gsub(/>|<.*/,"") && \
(($0 ~ /foo_bar.zip/) || ($0 ~ /foo_bar-[0-9]+.zip/))
'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
foo_bar.zip
foo_bar-12345.zip
```

**Explanation:** Adding a non-one liner form of solution with explanation too:

```
awk '
sub(/.[^>]*/,"") && \
gsub(/>|<.*/,"") && \
(($0 ~ /foo_bar.zip/) || ($0 ~ /foo_bar-[0-9]+.zip/))
##Substituting everything from starting to till first occurrence of > comes with NULL by using awk out of the box utility called sub.
##Globally substituting either > with NULL OR starting from < to everything with NULL.
##Now checking if after substituting above mentioned substitutions a line is equal to either foo_bar.zip OR foo_bar- then all digits till .zip
## Now point to be noted here that all conditions are joined with && means if first sub then gsub and then either of 3rd condition matches then only it should print line. awk works on condition then action method, in this solution I had mentioned conditions and NO action, so by default print of current line will happen.
' Input_file ## mentioning Input_file name here.
```